# TCP Socket data cleanup for text output

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to retrieve some data from a TCP Socket and write it out to a file.

I am able to retrieve the data fine, however I need to "sanitize it".

The data I receive has control codes to mark the begining of a report, and between each record. It also seems that there are NULL Characters between the CRLF codes.

My Data looks like this in an editor (I've masked the values):

```
 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLL LLLLLLLL                                     #,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                         #  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLL LL LLLLLLL                                   ###,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLLL                                            ##,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLL LLLLLLLL                                     #,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLL LLLL LLLLLL LLLLL                               #,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLLL LLLLLLL LLLLLL LLLLL                        #,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLL LLLLL LLLLLL  LLL                            #,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

*#########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLL LLLLL LLLLLL LLL                             #,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLLLLLLL LLLLLL LLLLL                            #,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLL LLLLL LLLLLL  LLL                            #,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLL LLL LLLL                                         ###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

 #########- #        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLLLL L LLLLLL LLL                               ##,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

    ######-##        L#########L ##############L                 LLLL LLLLLLLL                                      ##,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

    ######-##        L#########L ##############L                 LLLLL LLLLLLLLLL                                   ##,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######  

    ######-##        L#########L ##############L                 LLLL LLL                                           ##,###.##    ##/##/##    ##/##/##                    ######
```

This would be fine expect there is an extra carriage return I cannot get rid of(At the end), and the line endings look like this in a HEX Editor

00 20 00 0D 00 0D 00
0A 00

This is how I'm getting to where I am.

```
$new = $outputBuffer.Replace('[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]', '')

$str = $new.split("`n")

$myArray = @()

foreach ($line in $str) {
    $item = $line.trim([char]0x0003,[char]0x0002,[char]0x0001,[char]0x0000)

    if ($item -like "Out of*") {break}

    if ($item -ne "") {
        $myArray += $item
        }
}

$myArray | Out-File test.aud
```

The "Out of*" break is where I'm terminating the loop because that signals the end of the data I care about. The "Trim" when adding the line to the array is taking care of the Control Codes that mark the beginning/end of the report, but not the NULLs.

I have tried researching this for hours and cannot find a way to correct these line endings.

Thank You

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if your data was less masked.  Is there any way you could post something a little more useful?  Ideally with enough data that we could test the code you are running.

Comment: I would absolutely post better examples except this is Check Audit Data and therefore sensitive. I've found a way to resolve it which I posted as well. I'm sure there are better ways..

Comment: Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

I wound up fixing it by doing this

Writing it out with:

```
$myArray | Out-File dat.tmp
```

Then reading it back in, which fixed the line endings:

```
Get-Content dat.tmp | Set-Content $myVar".tmp"
```

But that caused an extra line between each record (Although my line endings are now true CRLF), so I did the read in/out again but this time selecting only the valid lines:

```
Select-String -Pattern '[^\s]' -Path $myVar".tmp" | ForEach-Object {$_.Line} | Set-Content -Path $myVar".aud"
```

I then cleaned up my temp files with:

```
Remove-Item dat.tmp
Remove-Item $myVar".tmp"
```

I'm certain there has to be a better way to do this, but this is working for now.